# Package explorer of Intellij IDEA like in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

Previously I used Eclipse, but now I am using Intellij IDEA. But I can't understand one thing. In Eclipse I have SETs in which I have a group of projects. At all I have a lot of different small projects to which I have simultaneous access and I see them all in the Package Explorer. In Intellij IDEA I see only one project, and this is not convenient for me.

Does Intellij IDEA have an analogue Package Explorer? How can I see many projects in one window?

Comment: Don't know if this is helpful, but: I will typically have one instance of IJ open for each project I am actively working on. IJ is more than happy to have multiple instances of the ide open at once. When you open the 2nd project, IJ will ask if you want to open in the same or different window. Just tell it different window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I believe you cannot open multiple unrelated projects in one window like you do in Eclipse.**

You'd need to open them in multiple windows, `File > Open ...` and you'll choose a new window. I also wished Intellij could open multiple projects in single window. But now I get used to it. Just click <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to switch between Intellij instances on OSX.

If they're modules of your project, then you can add them from `File > New > Module From Existing sources...`